# unexplained Gearman timeout mystery

Tags: php, pecl, gearman

Gearman client is timing-out randomly when adding a job. I cannot recreate the conditions to cause the failure. Gearman daemon is running!

Conditions: uploading a batch of files to be queued to Gearman for resizing. I can upload hundreds without error. However, every once and a while a single job will fail to be submitted with the following error:

```
 gearman_wait(GEARMAN_TIMEOUT) timeout reached,
 1 servers were poll(), no servers were available, pipe:false ->
 libgearman/universal.cc:328
```

However, the jobs submitted immediately before and after the failed job go through! I can even re-upload the same image and it goes through on the second attempt. The gearman server is there... is this some sort of glitch with gearmand or php-pecl-gearman extension??

gearmand config:

```
OPTIONS="
--port=4730 \
--verbose=NOTICE \
--log-file=/var/log/gearman/gearmand.log \
--keepalive \
--threads=4 \
--queue-type=MySQL \
--mysql-host=localhost \
--mysql-port=xxx \
--mysql-user=xx \
--mysql-password=xx \
--mysql-db=xxxD \
--mysql-table=gearman_queue \
--job-retries=5"
```

PHP Gearman Extension (PECL)

```
gearman support => enabled
extension version => 1.1.2
libgearman version => 1.1.8
Default TCP Host => localhost
Default TCP Port => 4730
```

Logs show all the jobs accepted, nothing noted for the failed job

```
NOTICE 2015-02-02 16:25:54.000000 [  proc ] accepted,worker_name,jobidprefix65468823354cfa51234fa09.3540767125336,0 -> libgearman-server/server.cc:314
 NOTICE 2015-02-02 16:25:56.000000 [  proc ] accepted,worker_name,jobidprefix40605707054cfa51438b0d0.383048589216,0 -> libgearman-server/server.cc:314
 NOTICE 2015-02-02 16:25:56.000000 [  proc ] accepted,worker_name,jobidprefix197198183754cfa51447dac9.5387112932157,0 -> libgearman-server/server.cc:314
```

Before submitting the job, I even ping the freaking gearman server to make sure that it is there! Ping result was true!!

```
$gmclient= new GearmanClient();
$gmclient->addServer("127.0.0.1", ((int)$gearmanPort)); # Add default server (localhost).
$gmclient->setTimeout(300);//set timeout to send gearman errors

//assign a unique id for the job (limit the length to prevent db errors)
$uniqueid = substr('jobPrefix'.uniqid (rand (),true).rand(0, 32767), 0, 63); 

//add the job to the background
$job_handle = $gmclient->addTaskBackground("worker_name", $jobdata, null, $uniqueid); 

//ping gearman to make sure it is working before sending job
//keep trying for 2 seconds (4 times per second) until success or failure
$pingCount = 1;
while (@$gmclient->ping(serialize("Ping Test")) === FALSE && $pingCount <= 8) {
            $this->log('Couldnt ping gearman server on pingCount='.$pingCount.'/8');
            usleep(250000); //sleep for 0.25 seconds before trying again
            $pingCount++;
}

//queue the job
if (@!$gmclient->runTasks()) //supress gearman fatal errors so we can catch them
{
    throw new CHttpException(500,"ERROR " . $gmclient->error());
}

if (@$gmclient->returnCode() != GEARMAN_SUCCESS) //supress gearman fatal errors so we can catch them
{
        throw new CHttpException(500,'ERROR: Bad return code for brokenlinkcheck '.$gmclient->returnCode());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`$gmclient->setTimeout(300);`

There's a nasty bug with timeouts when set for the worker in the gearman job server. Have you set a timeout in the worker script as well? Try to remove that.